# ReactNative AppState switches state multiple times on call

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm writing an app where I initiate a call and monitor the app state using the `AppState:change` listener.  I'm running into an issue where the app state switches between active & inactive multiple times while initiating the call.

Code:

```
componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChagne = (nextAppState) => {
  console.log(nextAppState);
}
```

on iOS, when I initiate the call, using `Linking.openURL('tel:1234567890')` and the logs show:

```
Inactive
Active
Inactive
```

on Android, the logs show:

```
background
active
background
```

I can hack around that by teaching my code to expect multiple changes, but that's not the most desirable approach.

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this on a real device or the simulator? I also notice similar behaviour, but only on the simulator

Comment: On iOS a real device.  On Android the simulator.  Can't test calls on the iOS simulator (which is silly).